# How to Include JavaScript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, tinymce

I am supposed to include this JavaScript in my `functions.php` file for WordPress.

```
tinymce.init({
        ...
        extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]"
});
```

I put this in `functions.php`, but it didn’t work. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'tinymce.init({
            ...
            extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]"
        });'
   , '</script>'
;
```

**EDIT:** Perhaps it would help if I explained what exactly I am trying to do. When I use the WordPress HTML editor to add icons like this

```
<span class="icon-shield"></span>
```

And then switch to the visual editor and then back to the HTML editor, the icons disappear. I am trying to include that bit of JavaScript above to fix this. I looked at `wp_enqueue_scripts` as suggested and put this in functions.php, but it still doesn’t fix the problem.

```
function oakwood_tinymcefix() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tiny_mce' );
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'tinymce.init({
            ...
            extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]"
        });'
   , '</script>';
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'oakwood_tinymcefix' );
```

Comment: have you checked whether the script is created or not?

Comment: Why you want add this from your function.php

Comment: Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: We've been having issues where an editor will make changes in the HTML editor in Wordpress and then switch to the visual editor, and then when they go back to the HTML editor, all of their changes are gone. My supervisor told me to add this piece of code and that would fix the issue...

Comment: get rid of those commas - why did you put them there? Also enclose the whole JS string in a single pair of quotes, don't stop and start them each line...

Comment: Stop looking at PHP and wondering why some JS doesn't work. Look at the source code that is sent to the browser. Is the JS there the JS you are expecting? If so, debug that. If not, start figuring out why PHP isn't outputting the text you expect.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, Quentin. I don't really know JS too well. Can you explain more?

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed enough in Javascript to be able to diagnose the problem in-browser. I think this may be a TinyMCE bug...

Comment: It your JavaScript isn't good enough to tell what the problem is when you look at the JavaScript, then it is not going to be good enough to tell what the problem is when you are looking at PHP.

Comment: It's not my Javascript. It's TinyMCE's Javascript that is automatically included with Wordpress...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like this:

```
echo <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
        ...
        extended_valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]"
});
</script>
EOT;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your JavaScript snippet do something with TinyMCE. You might want to load you js after TinyMCE is loaded.
Use this method instead in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'YOUR_SLUG_after_wp_tiny_mce' );
function YOUR_SLUG_after_wp_tiny_mce() {
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>',  plugins_url('/js/your-file.js', __FILE__) );
}
```